# How to enclose visually selected text with braces in vim

Tags: regex, vim, vim-plugin

I have a text like this:

```
NAME_1  : "Some name",
VALUE_1 : "Some text",
NAME_2  : "Some name2",
VALUE_2 : "Some text2",
....
```

How to transform this text to the following structure using vim scripting language or regex:

```
1 : {
    NAME  : "Some name",
    VALUE : "Some text"
},
2 : {
    NAME  : "Some name2",
    VALUE : "Some text2"
},
```

I was looking into the surround.vim plugin. It surrounds with braces well.
I tried to modify it to substract by pattern _(\d+) and then prepend this before the braces but I'm not quite familar with the vim scripting so I failed to do that.

Any advice will be appreciated greatly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with just one `:substitute`, using `\(...\)` capture groups, and re-arranging those submatches in the replacement part. It's only complex because there are several groups to juggle around, and because the pattern spans two lines.

```
:%s/^\(\w\+\)_\(\d\+\)\(\s*:\s*.*\)\n\(\w\+\)_\2\(\s*:\s*.*\),$/\2 : {\r    \1\3\r    \4\5\r},/
```

This matches two subsequent lines (note the `\n` in the pattern). By using the number (second capture group) in the second line, it ensures to get `NAME_1` and the corresponding `VALUE_2`.

Tip: This is easier to build as a search `/` first, then just reuse the pattern via `:%s//...`

In the replacement, the newlines are created via the `\r`. You'll find a more detailed explanation in the help under `:help :substitute`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do just two substitutions to solve this

```
%s,NAME_\d\+\,: {\r&,g
%s,VALUE_\d\+,&\r},

the "&" matches all things searched
\r inserts new line
```